# Allow Composer to downgrade a dependency on require?

Tags: composer-php

I have a package that I have installed through composer that required guzzlehttp `>=6.0`. With that requirement, composer chose to install 6.2.1.

I am now trying to require a dependency that explicitly requires 6.1.1.

I get the following error:

  `Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.1.1, 6.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.1, 6.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.1.1, 6.2.1].
    - chargely/chargify-sdk-php v0.1.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.1.1 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.1.1].
    - Installation request for chargely/chargify-sdk-php ^0.1.1 -> satisfiable by chargely/chargify-sdk-php[v0.1.1].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 6.2.1) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.1].`

Also, `composer why` confirms that the only that version of guzzle is there is because of my `>=6.0` requirement.

In theory, that initial requirement should be OK with using a downgraded version of guzzle. How do I get composer to do that?

Comment: What does your `composer.json` look like now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have 2 packages with **concurrency requirements**, you can go around with aliasing.

In your `composer.json`, just add:

```
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.2 as 6.1"
}
```

Then add new package with `composer require ...`.

Go check [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467982/1348344) for more.

Comment: I'm glad there's a way to do this, so thank you. It's a shame, though, that I have to explicitly define this in my main composer.json file when it's really about appeasing two of my dependencies (as opposed to my actual project). Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Simply "require" the correct version of the dependency, add the new package and then remove the hard-coded version constraint.

Summary (For a `vendor/current` with a constraint of vendor/dependency:"^1.0|^2.0")

```
composer require vendor/dependency:^1.0
composer require vendor/new
composer remove vendor/dependency
```

e.g.

1. For a `vendor/current` with a constraint of `vendor/dependency:"^1.0|^2.0"`
2. Composer would install the highest compatible version `vendor/dependency:2.x`
3. Then you try to install `vendor/new` with constraint of `vendor/dependency:"^1.0"` => FAIL (as you already have a too high installed vendor/dependency (of 2.0)
4. So then manually get the correct vendor/dependency version `composer require vendor/dependency:^1.0`
5. Get the new package `composer require vendor/new`
6. Remove hard coded constraint in composer.json `composer remove vendor/dependency`
7. Done.