# Composer, cant seem to get requirements right

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install a library, it was said in instructions to do it like this

```
composer require mailgun/mailgun-php php-http/curl-client guzzlehttp/psr7
```

but then I get  "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

so I try to set them right and in the end come down to

```
composer require mailgun/mailgun-php php-http/curl-client guzzlehttp/psr7 php-http/client-common:^1.1 php-http/httplug:^1.0 php-http/curl-client:^2.0
```

and then I get stuck with this message

```
php-http/curl-client 2.0.0 requires php-http/httplug ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability
```

which seems contrary to request before. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and how should I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve two packages requirements conflicts when running composer install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052831/how-to-solve-two-packages-requirements-conflicts-when-running-composer-install)

Comment: Maybe it could be similar but I am not using any dev-master versions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `composer require` tries to install the latest versions of the packages.  And in your case the latest versions can't satisfy all of the requirements. You could specify the version as `>0` and Composer would take older versions into consideration too when it tries to find the set of the dependencies that match all of your requirements. You can use `composer require mailgun/mailgun-php:">0" php-http/curl-client:">0" guzzlehttp/psr7:">0"` or set your `requires` value in your `composer.json` file to use any version from the oldest version onward:

```
"require": {
    "mailgun/mailgun-php": ">0",
    "php-http/curl-client": ">0",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": ">0"
}
```

and then run `composer update`.

Comment: This works, thanx. I guess you checked for latest packages with
composer show "mailgun/mailgun-php" --all   etc and then set it like this. Would like that composer somehow know this out of the box, but ok, glad that this works at least :)

Comment: Agreed, I would also have liked that composer does that out of the box! I see now that you can set the version requirement to ">0"  and it would have the same effect.