# Unable to require auth0 dependencies in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I'm using laravel 9.5 version and I wish to use the Auth0 to secure my API. Once, I enter the composer require auth0/login then I get failed with this error
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires auth0/login ^6.5 -> satisfiable by auth0/login[6.5.0, 6.x-dev].
- auth0/login[6.5.0, ..., 6.x-dev] require illuminate/support  ^6.0 || ^7.0 || ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with
another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require auth0/login:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require auth0/login:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\api> composer require auth0/login
Using version ^6.5 for auth0/login
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update auth0/login
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires auth0/login ^6.5 -> satisfiable by auth0/login[6.5.0, 6.x-dev].
- auth0/login[6.5.0, ..., 6.x-dev] require illuminate/support  ^6.0 || ^7.0 || ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with
another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require auth0/login:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require auth0/login:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content

Comment: What is your `php` version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve two packages requirements conflicts when running composer install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052831/how-to-solve-two-packages-requirements-conflicts-when-running-composer-install)

Comment: My php version is 8.1.2

Comment: I think that work fine for me, thank you